# jQuery how can I find the li that a div is in?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying

```
$(this).parent('li').attr('widgetid')
```

Because when I click within the following layout I want to find the widgetid

```
<li widgetid="1">
    <div class="widgetHeader">
        <div class="widgetIcon"></div>
        <div class="widgetTitle"></div>
        <div class="widgetEdit"></div>
        <div class="widgetClose"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="widgetHeader"></div>
</li>
```

but I am getting "undefined" so I think I lost myself "widgetClose" is the trigger div for what I am attempting to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
$(this).closest('li').attr('widgetid');
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.parents` along with `event.stopPropagation`

```
$("div").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
alert($(this).parents('li').attr('widgetid'));

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FhVgp/3/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the parent method with a selector (which will only return a value if the immediate parent matches the selector), you could use the parents method:

$(this).parents("li:eq(0)").attr("widgetid")

The parents method will look at all ancestor elements and return all that match the selector (in this case the selector asks for the first li that if found).

Answer (score 0):

You should bind only one click event listener for only the parent of all clickable elements anyway, then use event.target within the click function to refer to the clicked element.

From there, you can find the closest `<li>` element using jQuery `.closest()` method.